# Why cannot I use an instantiation of std::make_shared as a pointer to function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std

When a class has a default constructor, I can use the instantiation of `std::make_shared` in the same way as a **pointer to a function**. This is probably because the instantiated template has to be compiled and stored in memory and its address must exist.

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class DefaultConstructible
{
};

typedef std::function<std::shared_ptr<DefaultConstructible>()> Generator;

int main()
{
    Generator generator(std::make_shared<DefaultConstructible>);
    std::shared_ptr<DefaultConstructible> defConst = generator();

    return 0;
}
```

But the same thing fails when I add a non-trivial constructor:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class FromInt
{
public:
    FromInt(int a):a_(a){}
    int a_;
};

typedef std::function<std::shared_ptr<FromInt>(int)> Generator;

int main()
{
    Generator generator(std::make_shared<FromInt>);
    std::shared_ptr<FromInt> p = generator(2);

    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 
'std::function<std::shared_ptr<FromInt>(int)>::function(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     Generator g(std::make_shared<FromInt>);
                                          ^
```

Why is this so and how can I make my code compile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to be explicit about which constructor you want it to use:

```
Generator generator(std::make_shared<FromInt, int>);
```

The "extra" template argument(s) correspond to the constructor arguments.